# Importing Flat File into SQL Server stores incorrect dates In the database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am a SQL student who has been tasked with loading data into SQL Server for a company that I intern with.

I have tried loading multiple flat files with dates formatted as `1/23/04` into SSMS and when going through the wizard the dates preview correctly. Once they're loaded into the actual database and a `select` query is performed, all dates return as `2023-01-04` format.

I'm not sure where to even begin to fix this. I've loaded columns as `nvarchar(50)` as opposed to `date`, `datetime`, and `datetime2` to see if it would make a difference, and each case returns the same format. Is this a setting in the flat file, SSMS, or the computer itself?

Comment: Dates in SQL Server **do NOT** have any specific / given / fixed formatting - they're stored as multiple **binary byes**. The formatting / display only depends on the settings - either of SSMS as the management GUI tool, or your application.

Comment: That's true, @marc_s, but I think Darya's issue is that the input date of January 23, 2004 (I assume that's what 1/23/04 means) is getting imported as January 4, 2023.  (correct me if I'm wrong, Darya)

Comment: Also, Darya, could you please the DDL of your target table and a few sample lines from one of your flat files to your question?  Add them as text, please, so that we don't have to transcribe.

Comment: @Brian: good point - I hadn't paid attention to that

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS bring in the column (with the dates) as a string and add a derived column transform that will transform the column (using the substring function) to the correct date. SQL Server loves seeing dates as YYYY-MM-DD so that is why without explicitly telling it how to read the string it defaults to thinking that the inputted date is of that format.

If you are using SQL Server (SSMS) you should input it as a string (char(8)) and then use cast or convert functions to change the string into a date. You can then issue a 'Alter table drop column' to drop the string version column of the date.